# Wordpress Multisite SSL trouble

Tags: wordpress, ssl, https, multisite

Trouble with ssl wildcard.
I have wp multisite:
 site.com
with 3 networks:

```
n1.site.com
n2.site.com
n3.site.com
```

When i create new site in some network, my wildcard doesn't works on it
newsite.n1.site.com for example.

Do you know how remap domains for it to explode subnet in my domains?

Answer (score 0):

Wildcard certificates works only for one level.

You can:

- Get certificates like "*.n1.site.com" "*.n1.site.com" "*.n1.site.com" "*.n1.site.com" but it will be expensive
- Get certificates like "newsite.n1.site.com newsite.n2.site.com newsite.n3.site.com"

Comment: Thanks, but this is not best solution.. Is there any other suggestions?

Comment: @ВячеславРешетняков another alternative is to change your urls : site.com/n1/newsite (And you can get EV certificate!)

Comment: yeap, but i need domains like newsite.site.com/n1/

Answer (score 0):

Wildcard SSL certificate only support first level sub domains, it does not support second level sub domains. When wildcard certificate is issued for *.site.com, it can secure…

```
n1.site.com
n2.site.com
n3.site.com
```

If you want to secure second level sub domains like newsite.n1.site.com, then you have two choices…

**Multi Domain SSL**

If you have multiple websites and limited numbers of sub domains then multiple domain SSL certificate can protect up to 100 SANs where sub domains counts as additional subject alternative names.

**Multi Domain Wildcard SSL**

If you have multiple websites and want secure its unlimited numbers of sub domains, in that case multi domain wildcard SSL is an ideal solution.

Answer (score 0):

To secure newsite.n1.site.com website, you need to get wildcard SSL Certificate for *.n1.site.com.

Same way to secure newsite.n2.site.com, you need to get wildcard SSL certificate for *.n2.site.com...

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: A wildcard SSL Certificate for *.site.com can be able to secure following sub-domains

n1.site.com, n2.site.com, n3.site.com, or  anything.site.com... But you wish to secure newsite.n1.site.com, So for that you need to buy wildcard ssl for *.n1.site.com;  which can secure newsite.n1.site.com, newsite2.n1.site.com, newsite3.n1.site.com, anything.n1.site.com.